# wikipedia API - random article on given language

Tags: wikipedia-api

Is there any way to get a random article on a given language through the Wikipedia API?

I would like to do some linguistic analysis (finding common trigrams).

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&titles=Stack%20Overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is. Use `action=query` and `list=random` (and `rnlimit` to limit how many pages to get).

Example: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=random&format=json&rnnamespace=0&rnlimit=1

Or try it out in the [API Sandbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=query&list=random&format=json&rnnamespace=0&rnlimit=1).

Comment: this provides a random list of articles on any language - I would like to see a random list e.g. for English.

Comment: No, the command above only show random articles from the English Wikipedia. If you want it from another language you will have to change the first part of the URL. I.e. if you want Swedish instead of English use sv instead of en like this: https://sv.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=random&format=json&rnnamespace=0&rnlimit=1 Today, there is no way to get a random article from a random language through the API.